# Tensorflow.ValueError: Shape (3,4) must have rank at least 3

Tags: c#, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I'm using Tensorflow.NET to learn some neural networking. I've played around with other frameworks, but Keras seems to be one of the best right now. I'm stuck however on setting up my own basic time-series prediction.

```
int[,] X = new int[,] {  {1, 2, 3  },
                                {2, 3, 4 },
                                {3, 4, 5 },
                                {4, 5, 6 }  };

      int[] Y = new int[] { 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 };

      NDArray ndX = np.array(X);
      NDArray ndY = np.array(Y);
      
      Tensorflow.Keras.ArgsDefinition.SequentialArgs sequentialArgs = new Tensorflow.Keras.ArgsDefinition.SequentialArgs();

      Tensorflow.Keras.Engine.Sequential model = new Tensorflow.Keras.Engine.Sequential(sequentialArgs);

      Tensorflow.Keras.ArgsDefinition.Rnn.LSTMArgs lstmArgs = new Tensorflow.Keras.ArgsDefinition.Rnn.LSTMArgs();
      lstmArgs.Units = 4;
      lstmArgs.InputShape = new Shape(1,4);
      lstmArgs.ReturnSequences = false;
      lstmArgs.Activation = new Activations().Tanh;
      lstmArgs.RecurrentActivation = new Activations().Sigmoid;

      model.add(new Tensorflow.Keras.Layers.Rnn.LSTM(lstmArgs));

      Tensorflow.Keras.ArgsDefinition.DenseArgs denseArgs = new Tensorflow.Keras.ArgsDefinition.DenseArgs();
      denseArgs.Units = 2;

      model.add(new Tensorflow.Keras.Layers.Dense(denseArgs));
      model.compile("adam", "mse", new string[]{"accuracy"});
      model.fit(ndX, ndY, batch_size:4, epochs:200, verbose:2);
```

The last line, model.fit is where I'm getting the message in the title.

I've played around with the dimensions of my input array, changing it to have 3 dimensions, and the Y array to have 2 dimensions. I also adjusted the lstmArgs.InputShape, but that didn't seem to have any effect. I'm definitely not entirely understanding something about the relationship of the dimensions of the input arrays.